# jQuery ajax doesn't send a response

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, post

I am sending data to a specific URL and then I try to get it with ajax it just prints up an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf2K2.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/computers/{{id}}",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        succsess: function(data){
            var json = $.parseJSON(data); // create an object with the key of the array
            alert(json.html);
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(error){
         console.log("Error:");
         console.log(error);
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

^ that's how I receive the request (the id is 2)

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: @L0uis I linked it I can't even understand the error It's kinda weird
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
that's the main part if it tells you something

Comment: Not entirely sure yet, doing some research. But, could you confirm you don't need to pass local host in `ajax({ ... url: "127.0.0.1/computers{{id}} ... });`. I'm asking because it could be your browser thinking its opening a local directory with `/computers/{{id}}`.

Comment: @zerecees It's actually my ipv4(I hid it) I don't think it really matters I can see the post request in  the "Network" tab

Comment: Gotcha. Ok, I'm still googling. Give me a few. Hopefully I'll get something concrete. I, too, don't understand the error.

Comment: I think it's because you spelled `success` as `succsess` in `$.ajax({ ... success: ...})`. Try changing the spelling (Fingers crossed)

Comment: @zerecees I didn't noticed that but still, same error

Comment: In your console, do you see "Error:" above the log in the screenshot you posted? Trying to discern if we're looking at the right error message.

Comment: @zerecees Yeah.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not turning up much as I'm not an expert in AJAX. However, if I find something I'll be sure to keep you updated. So sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: @zerecees I found something... So I worked the problem was that I did type Json weird I know... anyway it just prints the source code when it goes to success

Comment: Happens. Don't sweat it. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @zerecees I mean It should be JSON I am even more confused than before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I am not sending any data but I am also typing that `dataType: "json"` So that made the error.

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/computers/{{id}}",
        async: true,
        succsess: function(data){
            var json = $.parseJSON(data); // create an object with the key of the array
            alert(json.html);
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(error){
         console.log("Error:");
         console.log(error);
    }
    });
```

So this is the correct code because I am not sending any data.